# Visual Studio android sdk newer version is requied

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

In Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin I installed android SDK and updated it. Android SDK manager says, that I have tools version 25.2.3:

[image: See image].

But Visual Studio still shows up a message that I must update it:

[image: See image].

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you confirm for us that your `Android SDK` location is the correct one? Is the `Android SDK` that loads up in your screenshot the same path from the `Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager`? As another sanity check, you can look at your `Build Output` for the path of the `Android SDK`.

Comment: I've got correct path to location, it is the same one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've came across the same problem yesterday, to solve this issue, you must download the **Android 6.0(API 23)**. After that the designer should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I had to scroll down and install any Android API.